# JAVA + SQLite - get a formatted date from each row using strftime()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I've been using SQLite for about a day now and have managed to get reading and writing working in Android Studio using Java. I'm still pretty new to all this, even java, so I may be missing something pretty basic.

I managed to get something working yesterday with the desired outcome. I would save the Year, month, ..., second into their own column and then read them individually and manually format them into a string. However today I read that SQLite has its own built-in date and time functions when you store it as text in a specific format.

I have changed everything to use this format instead, that was easy, but I'm struggling to read the date in a specific format. Right now the format is:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

However, I would like to format it as:

> yyyy : MM : dd : HH : mm : ss

I just store it in a string list as of now, that works and I assume I don't need to change that.

Here is the code that reads the dates:

```
public ArrayList readHistory(){
        SQLiteDatabase nutDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ArrayList<String> history = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor cursor = nutDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            String nutString = cursor.getString(dateTime);
            history.add(nutString);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return history;
    }
```

As you can see, it currently just gets it as a string how it's currently formatted. I have no idea how to implement strftime() but I know its exactly what I need.

Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Since you say that you are pretty new to this I definitely suggest you to make a research about ROOM and MVVM, because it is way more easy to use SQLite in that way. For example, check this codelab: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0

Comment: @Antonio I'll look at that, thanks. If it requires big changes to the structure then I'd rather just get this working because I just need to know how to use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the format `'%Y : %m : %d : %H : %M : %S'` in `strftime()`.
So change your code to:

```
String sql = "SELECT strftime('%Y : %m : %d : %H : %M : %S', dateTime) AS dateTime FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
Cursor cursor = nutDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Comment: Thank You so much for this! It crashed every time I ran the code until I realised I needed to change the column index from dateTime (1) to 0.

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

An alternative to solving it using SQL, you can solve it using *java.time* API as shown below:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // A sample date-time string. In your code, it will come from
        // cursor.getString(dateTime)
        String nutString = "2020-01-10 20:30:40";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(nutString, dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu : MM : dd HH : mm : ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(ldt);
        System.out.println(formatted);
        // history.add(formatted);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020 : 01 : 10 20 : 30 : 40
```

As you can see in the code, you need two instances of `DateTimeFormatter` - one to parse the date-time string, you are retrieving from DB, into `LocalDateTime` and another to format the `LocalDateTime` to a `String` in the desired format.

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.